# Print multiple variables with one command in GDB

Tags: gdb

I want to execute the very simple command

```
print var1, var2, var3, var4
```

in gdb to examine the values of the vars from time to time.

I don't want to use display because it clutters up my view.

*How can I do this?* Right now all I can do is:

```
p var1  
p var2  
p var3  
p var4
```

Comment: Its amazing its 2016 and this issue is still present.

Comment: Now it's 2019. Still here. Happy new year!

Comment: Oof, now it's 2020

Comment: This thread looks like youtube comments :D P.S. 2021 yeye...

Comment: Looks like 2015 saw the fix...what are you guys complaining about? Perhaps the end of 2021 will see the end of this comment thread.

Answer (score 67):

You can simply do this

```
print {var1,var2,var3,var4}
```

This will do the job.

Comment: I run into error `array elements must all be the same size`.

Comment: This is quick and easy, but only if they are all the same type, or you can cast them usefully to the same type.

Answer (score 49):

Use the printf command. It's a bit of a hassle, but it gives good control over the formatting. From the command line:

```
(gdb) help printf
printf "printf format string", arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., argn
This is useful for formatted output in user-defined commands.
```

The format string is like in C (%d for normal size ints, %s for null terminated strings, etc.).

Comment: I like this answer.  One niche problem with it is that it only supports up to 64-bit integers: `That operation is not available on integers of more than 8 bytes.`  (GCC on AMD64 has emulated `__int128_t` on some platforms.)  Of course, you can shift and cast.

Answer (score 31):

Use Macros:

For example to continue to next break point and print

```
(gdb) define prm
```

Type commands for definition of `prm`.
End with a line saying just `end`.

```
>continue
>print var1
>print var2
>print var3
>end

(gdb) prm
$5 = 0
$6 = 10
$7 = -1
```

Comment: this just changed how I use gdb forever

Answer (score 2):

There may be a simpler solution, but you might be able to put together something using GDB macros: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-gdb.html