# Printing multiple variables in GDB?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I am encountering a problem to print multiple variables (`say 25`) in a function on `GDB Prompt`.

Is there any convenient way to do this instead of printing every variables manually ?

can I have a script or a simpler way which can do my job ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gdb - print multiple variables with one command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882857/gdb-print-multiple-variables-with-one-command)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can print multiple values using `printf` command in gdb.

```
printf "%d,%d\n", a, b
```

To use it in future, you can either define a gdb-function or use gdb-history feature.

1. To define a gdb-function, create/modify file `$HOME/.gdbinit` with the following conten,

   ```
   define print_all
       printf "%d,%d\n", a, b
   end
   document print_all
       Prints all my variables.
   end
   ```

   Then you can use `print_all` as a command.
2. For history trick, create/modify file `$HOME/.gdbinit` with the following content:

   ```
   set history filename ~/.gdb_history
   set history save
   ```

   and get it using `ctrl+r` same like in bash.
   Actual gdb-history answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176800/how-can-i-make-gdb-save-the-command-history).

Comment: @Jeyaram, I have no experience on different linux distros, but you can use `-x` option to specify command file if it is not picked from `$HOME/.gdbinit`. Ex.: `gdb -x /path/.gdbinit /path/binary`

Comment: It seems can't print register.