# Print multiple variables with one command in LLDB

Tags: lldb

This is possible with [Print multiple variables with one command in GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1882857), but how to do it with `LLDB`?

Answer (score 8):

If all you want is to print variables, then

```
(lldb) frame variable var1 var2 var3 var4
```

will do it for you

But if you're trying to actually evaluate expressions instead of just printing local variables, then that will not work.

Comment: Even better with `fr v -o var1 var2 var3 var4`

Answer (score 7):

To get the same result , you can log messages with Xcode Breakpoints.

writing:

> @var1@ @var2@ @var3@ @var4@

more details:

> var1 is @var1@ , var2 is  @var2@, var3 is @var3@ , var4 is @var4@

showing a pic:

[image: one]

#### more intuitive, you could use multiple debug command

just like

[image: two]